# Indy9コンポーネントの”Athread->Stopped”の値はIndy10ではどうやって記述すればいい？

Tags: rad-studio

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

Indy9のTCPサーバのコンポーネントを使用したソースコードを見たのですが、
`Athread->Stopped` と記述されたプログラムは、Indy10の場合どのように記述すれば同様の値を取得できますか？

ちなみに、私が見たソースコードはこのようなものでした。

```cpp
//Indy9のServerConnectメソッドのソース内容（Borland C++ builder 6でビルド）
*void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
---------（中略）---------

    if( AThread->Stopped || AThread->Terminated ) return;

---------（中略）---------
}
```

**（途中経過）**

```cpp
//RAD Studio 10.3で、Indy10コンポーネントの場合のServerConnectメソッド
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{

}
```

RAD studio10.3.3では、Indy10のコンポーネントの場合、ServerConnectメソッドの引数部分は`(TIdContext *AContext)` となっています。

Indy10のドキュメントで”Stopped”というキーワードで検索してみたところ、"TIdThread"というところに”Stopped”というのがあるようなのですが、このメソッド内のAContextからこのStoppedの値を取り出すことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[本家の似た質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566643/tidpeerthread-returnvalue-not-indy10)の回答によるとTIdContext.Yarn を経由する事でThreadにアクセス出来るようですので
以下ようなコードになるのでは無いでしょうか？
コンパイルするにはIdSchedulerOfThread.hppのインクルードが必要かもしれません。

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
---------（中略）---------

    if( TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn)->Thread->Stopped 
       || TIdYarnOfThread(AContext.Yarn)->Thread->Terminated ) return;

---------（中略）---------
}
```

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。
頂いたコードをそのまま入れてビルドしてみました。
```
[bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(480): no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'Idyarn::TIdYarn *' to 'Idschedulerofthread::TIdYarnOfThread'
  IdSchedulerOfThread.hpp(37): candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'Idyarn::TIdYarn *' to 'const Idschedulerofthread::TIdYarnOfThread' for 1st argument
  IdSchedulerOfThread.hpp(46): candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
```
このような結果がでてきたのですが、対策方法などありますでしょうか？

Comment: 類似の質問の紹介ありがとうございます。活用させて頂きます。

Comment: http://www.borlandforum.com/impboard/impboard.dll?action=read&db=bcb_qna&no=61566

こちらのサイトの方の方法から、
 if( ((TIdYarnOfThread*)(AContext->Yarn))->Thread->Stopped
    || ((TIdYarnOfThread*)(AContext->Yarn))->Thread->Terminated ) return;

この方法でビルド成功しました。